# Soft Keyboard not opening for second time once closed keyboard in Textfield compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield, android-softkeyboard

I am new to Compose. Faced issue on compose Textfield when I try to implement an UI which takes input from user. As soon as click Textfield soft Keyboard opened immediately on first time and able to enter text. After that I closed soft keyboard and clicked again on Textfield but keyboard not opened. Even I have tried some applications which is available on Playstore as well. But it works well on XML view based application.

Soft keyboard should open whenever click the Textfield in compose.

Answer (score 0):

I want to further clarify the solution that @ananth found:

There was an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/311437241) in Jetpack Compose that was already fixed in the latest library version.
Make sure that you are using the latest Jetpack Compose UI dependency V`1.6.0-rc01`:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.6.0-rc01"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have tried above method but still same. Issue resolved by updating compose dependency version to 1.6.0-beta03.